# Should our confidence in god decrease the longer we go without finding clear cut evidence of Him?

Tags: theology, atheism

Every mystery we ever had to solve that was solved in some way was explained through natural causes. This includes the diversification of life, thunder, etc.

On the one hand, the large amount of time we’ve had in investigating matters and not seeing any definitive evidence of god seems to count as evidence only against a specific type of god: a god who would directly intervene in an obvious way. For example, clearly, a god who decides to speak a voice from the clouds where the entire globe can hear it and says “Here I am” in 2022 does not exist. For otherwise, this would have happened and been recorded.

On the other hand, the invisible and the nonexistent look alike. Similarly, absence of evidence often looks like evidence of absence. And the longer this goes, the more surprising it would seem, atleast intuitively, to find out that god indeed does exist.

So should we decrease our confidence in god the longer we go not finding him?

Comment: It depends on the offer of your God. Some forgive any sin, others are quite demanding.

Comment: @RodolfoAP I think that denying the existence of God is the only 'unforgivable' sin, because the unbeliever won't accept anything from God, and God won't override their free will. So the stakes are pretty high. A really tough God would provide no evidence but punish you eternally for not believing. It is like a Trolley Problem.

Comment: What "confidence"... belief in god is faith.

Comment: What material thing could you see that would convince you of the existence of an immaterial existence?